# Физически нет любого созданного файла/папки на Android

Tags: java, android

Создаю в коде обычно-привычными строчками File ... = new File(...); пустую папку в Android, которая и вправду создалась, но и не совсем. В проводнике я смогу увидеть эту папку в той директории, указав я ещё на моменте создания, но вот соединив моё устройство с ПК через USB переходник и перейдя по тому самому пути до директории, где расположена моя недавно сотворённая папочка, я увижу, что её там нет!

Как так? Подскажите, почему так, братцы и как это исправить?

Comment: В системе Андроид надо понимать где создаешь и что из этого следует. Тут все расписано: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: Нажать правой кнопкой по директории и "Synchronize" пробовали?

Comment: @sakuraso13 неа, не пробовал. А где это именно? Можно пожалуйста поподробней! =D

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja вроде всё правильно я делаю, а именно через new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "test"); , но и после этого в самом окне на ПК папка отсутствует, а если создавать так фотографию, то ей даже поделиться нельзя! При загрузке будет ошибка. Просто на иконке прикрепленного изображения под EditText мессенджера появится текст "Ошибка". Как так то?!

Comment: @Prot_CN https://i.imgur.com/lbYK0VI.png